# What university is Monsters University modeled after?

Tags: monsters-university

Is Monsters University modeled after a specific university, and if so, what university? After watching the movie, the campus seems familiar to me, but I can't pick out exactly what it is.

Comment: It looks so Northwestern U. to me... It reminded me of my old school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.businessinsider.com/buildings-inspire-monsters-university-2013-7?op=1), inspiration from the Monsters U campus draws from schools Pixar animators flew out to research on, such as Princeton, Harvard, Stanford, UC Berkeley.

From the source:

> These campus visits helped the animators create a collegiate
>   environment that while not based on any one school, had a mix of
>   California and East Coast university traditions, Robert Kondo, Monster
>   University's Art Director for Set Design & Shading, told us.
>
> Kondo told Business Insider that because a lot of the animators went
>   to art school, they traveled to these campuses to get an understanding
>   of a more all around university experience. More than looking at
>   specific buildings, though, Kondo said — as only an art school grad
>   could — that the team went to "absorb the feeling" of their element.

Some specific example they cite are:

- The Troll Bridge in Monsters is an almost mirror image of the Weeks Footbridge at Harvard
  [image]
  [image]
- Parts of Monsters U have arches monsters can walk under, a callback to Stanford University's arched hallways
  [image]
  [image]
- The schoolgates to Monsters U resemble the gates to Princeton University.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130615024238/http://calibermag.org/articles/monsters-university-vs-uc-berkeley/), Monsters University is at least partly modeled on UC Berkeley.  The article has several illustrations showing how familiar Berkeley landmarks such as Sather Gate and the Campanile are copied in the film.

Comment: That appears to be a dead link to me.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Worse than dead; it took me to a malware site.  I've replaced it with a link to a clunky but still useful snapshot from the Internet Archive.

Answer (score -4):

Google again... They said several colleges but mostly U. c Berkley, MIT Harvard and other schools the artists went to

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: Please do elaborate - both with a source, and with more detail. e.g. You say that the artists went to some of the schools that they drew inspiration from - can you give some of the artists' names and tell us what school(s) they specifically went to? (You can add all this to your post by clicking the "edit" button beneath it.) Thanks!

Comment: Who is this "They?"

Answer (score -6):

The university is clearly modeled after the University of Michigan in Ann Arbor. With the large campus, student population, and popular Greek life it must be this university. Hail to the victors

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). You might want to back up your claims somehow to flesh out the answer a little more.